# Let $a$ and $c$ are unit vectors and $|b| =4$ with $a \times b = 2a \times c$ .....

Tags: vectors

Problem :

Let $a$ and $c$ are unit vectors and $|b| =4$ with $a \times b = 2a \times c$ The angle between $a$ and $c$  is $\arccos (\frac{1}{4})$. If $b-2c =\lambda a$ then find $\lambda$

My approach :

Since $a$ and $c$ are unit vectors $\Rightarrow |a| =|c| = 1$

we have $a.c =|a||c|cos\theta$

$\Rightarrow a.c = 1 . 1 \frac{1}{4}$

Please suggest how to proceed further to get $\lambda$ will be of great help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$b=\lambda a+2c \Rightarrow b \cdot a= \lambda |a|^2 +2a\cdot c \Rightarrow \lambda=a\cdot b-1/2 \quad (1)$$

$$a \times b = 2a \times c \Rightarrow 1\cdot 4\cdot \sin \alpha=2\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot \sin \theta \quad (2)$$

but $\sin \theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{1-(1/4)^2}=\sqrt{15}/4$ and so $\sin \alpha=\sqrt{15}/8$

$$a\cdot b= \cos \alpha$$

Answer (score 1):

$$|a||b|\sin\theta=2|a||c|\times \frac {\sqrt{15}}{4} \implies \sin\theta=\frac  {\sqrt{15}}{8} $$
and
$$a.b=|a||b|\cos\theta=\frac {7}{2}$$
on the other hand
$$(b+\lambda a)\cdot(b+\lambda a)=c\cdot c$$
thus
$$|b|^2+2\lambda b\cdot a+|a|^2=|c|^2$$